# Вывод в две колонки, flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Ни как не получается реализовать вывод в две колонки, так, чтобы каждый столбец занимал ровно 50% места, а по высоте они отличались (сейчас, почему то, по высоте блоки совпадают, не могу понять почему).

Т.е. хочется примерно такой вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Сори за простыню HTML'a.

```css
.events {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.events .event {
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="events"><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837436/v837436261/5dac8/g54e07y7Hzc.jpg" alt="ПАША ТЕХНИК | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ПАША ТЕХНИК | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ</div><div class="text">Два Кремля Промо представляет :

Паша Техник — в Краснодаре!
Не пропустите концерт основателя и вдохновителя эпатажной андерграунд группировки Kunteynir.
Творчество Паши Техника это настоящий андерграунд. Всем известный по выступлению на Versus Battle. Тексты наполнены неоднозначным смыслом и жизненными историями. Ребята едут в тур с поддержкой нового альбома, клипа и совершенно новым ШОУ, а так же вспомнить старые добрые треки группы KUNTEYNIR

============================
18 ноября 
Клуб : СУ-27 
Адрес: ул. Ставропольская,208
Вход с 19.00
Начало в 20.00</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул. Ставропольская,208, СУ-27</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837726/v837726550/566e3/mWWg0e-U7BY.jpg" alt="ATL | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ @ ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ATL | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ @ ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">ATL возвращается в Краснодар уже этой осенью, 18 НОЯБРЯ , ARENA HALL в рамках тура "HOLY RAVE" с новой,большой концертной программой. 

Презентация альбома "ЛИМБ" , который вызвал шквал положительных  эмоций и хороших отзывов,а также Сергей исполнит все Хиты с предыдущих альбомов и микстэйпов !
---------------------------------------------
STANDART-1000Р
FUN ZONE-1500P
-
VIP-2000P
SUPER VIP-5000P

-Купить билеты можно:

⚫ Бургерная "Краснодарский Парень" 
Адрес: 
Ул. Северная,358
(между Красной и Красноармейской, по стороне ТЦ Галерея, в пяти минутах от ТЦ).

⏱Часы работы:
Вс-пт 12:00-23:00 
Сб 12:00-00:00

⚫"KEDS SHOP"
Адрес: 
Ул.Красная,176 
ТК "ЦЕНТР ГОРОДА"

⏱Часы работы:
С 10:00-21:00
Без перерыва и выходных

⚫ "HYPESTORE"
Адрес:
Ул.Уральская,79/1
ТРК "СБС Мегамолл"
2 этаж ( возле магазина H&amp;M )

⏱Часы работы:
С 10:00-22:00
Без перерыва и выходных

⚫Кофейня "TREND COFFEE SHOP"
-Адрес: 
ТЦ ОЗ молл (ул. Крылатая 2) 
Вход со стороны "Спортмастера" 

⏱Часы работы: 10:00-22:00
Без выходных

»»КУПИТЬ БИЛЕТЫ:

-ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ БИЛЕТЫ:

• http://acidhouze.ru/

• https://krasnodar.qtickets.events/834-atl

-БИЛЕТЫ на KASSIR:

•Купить: https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/arena-hall/atl_2017-1…

•Точки продаж: https://m.vk.com/topic-151519769_36069656

-БИЛЕТЫ на 23БИЛЕТА:

•Купить: http://23bileta.ru/events/concerts/atl_krd/

•Точки продаж: https://m.vk.com/topic-151519769_36069664</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">вишняковой 1\10, arena hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841035/v841035052/24751/JQTBqPp-YT8.jpg" alt="ИЗМОРОЗЬ | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ИЗМОРОЗЬ | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ</div><div class="text">⚡ИЗМОРОЗЬ - самая скандальная группа российской металл-сцены. Люди в чёрном запрещают их концерты на крупных площадках столицы, а лейблы готовы воевать друг с другом за издание их альбомов! 
Фанаты группы начинают устраивать слэм уже в очередях за билетами, пытаясь попасть на их концерты, но они выступают всего несколько раз в год….. 
Тексты группе своей дрожащей старческой рукой выводит загадочная Проскофья Матвеевна, от чего все «тру» металлисты либо погружаются в адовое веселье, либо сжигают диски на костре святой инквизиции. 
Песни посвящены викингам, а также различным геройским героям-воинам, нашим славянским божествам и легендам, которые частенько упоминаются в текстах. 
Здесь нет сложных ходов и гитарных запилов, зато есть запоминающиеся мелодии, броская лирика, разнообразные вокальные ходы, угар и веселье! 
Смешайте фолк, паган, блэк, добавьте юмора и приправьте всё это солью, перцем и пивом! И вы получите то, с чего никогда не замёрзнете – ИЗМОРОЗЬ. 
 
Только 18 ноября в The Rock Bar есть уникальная возможность увидеть и услышать их в «живую»! 

БИЛЕТЫ: 
В предпродаже: первые 30 билетов по 400 р. (только в The Rock Bar ,ул. Горького, 104), 
Остальные и на сайте 500р. по ссылке - https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/rock-bar/izmoroz_2017-11-18_1800

На входе 700р.</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836738/v836738163/52748/4zcKWejkmi0.jpg" alt="ATL | 18 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ATL | 18 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">Дата: 18 ноября
18:00 - Открытие дверей 
19:00 - концерт 
Место проведения: ARENA HALL, ул.Вишняковой 1/10
______________________________________
Купить Билеты: 23bileta.ru/events/concerts/atl_krd/?sphrase_id=6476

Сергей Круппов, он же ATL — талантливый исполнитель из города Новочебоксарск, представитель Белой Чувашии, разрывающий любые клубы, своими уникальными, в некотором смысле, по энергетике выступлениями.
На данный момент ATL имеет на своём счету уже 11 сольных релизов, регулярные концерты, выступление на баттле «Versus», где он одержал победу над Энди Картрайтом, а самое главное — свой уникальный стиль, наработанный годами и делающий Сергея одним из ведущих исполнителей в выбранном им творческом направлении.</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Вишняковой 1/10, Arena Hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837720/v837720877/2fe8b/Y0JhD9itJhI.jpg" alt="ДИСКОТЕКА 80-х и 90-х | КРАСНОДАР 18 ноября 2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ДИСКОТЕКА 80-х и 90-х | КРАСНОДАР 18 ноября 2017</div><div class="text">Легендарная и зажигательная Дискотека 80-х и 90-х в Краснодаре.
Будет проходить 18 ноября на сцене Баскет Холл. 
Юрий Шатунов;
Тото Кутуньо;
Валерия;
Томас Андерс;
Игорь Николаев;
Сабрина;
Оттаван;
Алексей Глызин и др.
Купить билеты в кассе или на сайте онлайн:
bil24.ru
biletovpachka.ru
Обратите внимание, что билеты предлагаются с местами или на танцпол.
Приглашаем!
Это будет незабываемый Дискач!!!</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">пригородная, 24, Баскет Холл</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c638627/v638627544/45715/pXHdO4d-ZnI.jpg" alt="ЙОРШ ||► Краснодар, 18.11.2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ЙОРШ ||► Краснодар, 18.11.2017</div><div class="text">Обжигающим светом во тьму осенней серости ворвётся музыка сильных! 
Грядущий тур группа Йорш обещает сделать особенно жарким и запоминающимся. 

Музыканты собственным примером покажут, как одна маленькая свеча может разогнать кромешную темноту и пугающий мрак. Программа #сквозьтьму станет откровенным ответом на вопросы, которые не каждый решается задать даже самому себе. 

В рамках осеннего тура Йорш разожжет огонь настоящего рока не только на площадках нашей страны, но и вырвется за ее пределы!</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T17:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841033/v841033214/396f2/5JFzxmOXt_g.jpg" alt="Легенды Русского Панка @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Легенды Русского Панка @TheRockBar</div><div class="text"> Хей, хей хей!!!! Отличная новость для любителей русского панк рока!!! 
 
 Группа РазДва, хорошо известная всем по музыкально-театральным отрывам в стиле «короля и Шута», подготовила огненную подборку отечественных хитов самого протестного стиля музыки!!! 

Панк шлягеры таких групп как: Бригадный подряд, Наив, Тараканы, Сектор Газа, Гроб, Fpg, Ляпис Трубецкой, ну и конечно же любимые Киш!!! Так же вас будут ожидать разнообразные сюрпризы, атмосфера легкого безобразия и баловства!!! 

Причесывай свой седой гребень и гоу к нам!!!! 

 #TheRockBar / 18 ноября / в 23-00 / 300₽</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T20:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c840236/v840236029/30f7d/3vY5xjHJaOw.jpg" alt="LOBODA | 20 НОЯБРЯ | КРАСНОДАР | ДС ОЛИМП"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">LOBODA | 20 НОЯБРЯ | КРАСНОДАР | ДС ОЛИМП</div><div class="text">Разыгрываем два билета на концерт LOBODA 
⚡Будет 1 победитель!!! ⚡ (2 билета в руки) 
Условия ниже: 
1. Быть участником нашей встречи 
LOBODA  
 
2. Сделать #РЕПОСТ данной записи 18.11.2017 в 22:00 
с помощью рандомного сервиса мы выберем победителя. 
 
Билеты можно приобрести 
Онлайн : https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/ds-olimp/loboda_2017-11-20_1900 
Телефон : 8(861)203-47-87</div><div class="date">2017-11-20T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c840232/v840232133/454a4/qtoUFJJxs5A.jpg" alt="ТЕМПЕРА-ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR 23.11.17"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ТЕМПЕРА-ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR 23.11.17</div><div class="text">Выставка Краснодарских художников, разнообразных стилей и направлений в стенах SGT. PEPPER'S BAR в рамках литературно-поэтического клуба "ПОЭТИКА". 
Мир красок, глубина цвета и неисчерпаемое звучание изобразительного искусства.</div><div class="date">2017-11-23T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул.Чапаева 94, Sgt. Pepper's Bar</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841026/v841026100/36337/vufWFflwHfQ.jpg" alt="ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR | 23.11.2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR | 23.11.2017</div><div class="text">Литературно-поэтический клуб г. Краснодара "ПОЭТИКА".
Русское слово, всегда было самой сутью нашей культуры, русская словесность поэзия, проза, и литература всемирно признанный знак качества. 

В лучшем месте г. Краснодара, в атмосфере уюта, Вы можете послушать поэтов, писателей и литераторов, тех кто через слово доносит свои идеи и открыто смотрит на мир.

Список авторов что будут жечь глаголом и звучанием сердца 23.11.2017
https://vk.com/yarmadov Арсений Ярмадов
https://vk.com/mousereepicheep Артем Козин
https://vk.com/mirror_poison Мирро Пуазон
https://vk.com/bes.dobra Артем и Коста Франич
https://vk.com/kosolapova95 Анастасия Косолапова
https://vk.com/id26336024 Лина Сальникова
https://vk.com/projectaz Школа кино "Артанде"
https://vk.com/domvlatov Андрей Домлатов
https://vk.com/id27085992 Арсен Брусенский
https://vk.com/vezdelesa Юля Постыка
https://vk.com/olejagger Олег Савранский
https://vk.com/grumpyoldman Евгений Полуянцев
https://vk.com/kain_vega Kain Vega
https://vk.com/janepaladi Евгения Баксараева</div><div class="date">2017-11-23T17:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул. Чапаева, 94, Sgt. Pepper's Bar</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841537/v841537136/2be74/k9jZCTJCzqU.jpg" alt="АНТОХА МС - Краснодар @Sgt.Pepper's Bar 24.11"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">АНТОХА МС - Краснодар @Sgt.Pepper's Bar 24.11</div><div class="text">Антоха МС - самое заметное и оригинальное явление на отечественной сцене за последнее время. Артист, которого нужно слушать живьем, всю музыку и тексты пишет сам, подыгрывает себе же на трубе.
Лирика, пропитанная романтикой двора, черный грув, искренность и самобытность - всё это есть в его песнях. «Нести добро» — один из его творческих принципов. На своих концертах Антоха МС делает так, что зрительный зал становится с ним единым целом.
Вот что говорит об новом альбоме сам артист:
"Данной работой мы желаем поддержать тех кто движется по самостоятельному пути, ищет опоры движения по жизни. Названием альбома - «Советы для молодожёнов» - мы желали отобразить одну из самых важных на наш взгляд тем социума - «Семья», содержимым альбома порадовать слушателей хорошим тоном, точным ритмом, родным, знакомым и новым ответом и вопросом - «Что к чему».  Приятного прослушивания."
Антоха МС - Антон Кузнецов.

Начало: 24 ноября в 19:00 
Билеты можно купить на баре в Sgt. Pepper's Bar по 800 р.
Билет на двоих: 1400 р.
Билет на троих: 2000 р. 
Электронные билеты: https://vk.cc/7g4Hch
Возрастное ограничение: 16+
Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94) 
Тел. для справок: 8 (861) 944-13-99 

#SgtPeppersBar #АнтохаМС</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837223/v837223500/575d3/3BALaOHaD7Q.jpg" alt="24 ноября - СЭТ @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24 ноября - СЭТ @TheRockBar</div><div class="text">Один из главных краснодарских артистов объявил о перезапуске своей карьеры. 
 
24 ноября в The Rock Bar - эксклюзивно, до выхода нового релиза - СЭТ презентует абсолютно новые треки и исполнит свое лучшее из 5-ти изданных альбомов, в том числе хиты, записанные с Кастой, Krec, Триадой, L'One и др. 
 
Концерт пройдет при участии живого бэнда. Специальные гости: Лейла и PLC.
 
Билеты: 
Билеты в предпродаже по 500р в The Rock Bar на Горького, 104 или по ссылке - https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/rock-bar/set_2017-11-24_1900
В день концерта 700р</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639918/v639918568/620db/BuhJ1OhDShU.jpg" alt="24.11 - Дана Соколова @ Краснодар"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24.11 - Дана Соколова @ Краснодар</div><div class="text">24 ноября в краснодарском клубе Arena Hall состоится большой сольный концерт Даны Соколовой ! 

Подробности: https://vk.com/danakrasnodar 

Подробная информация о билетах доступна по ссылке: https://dana.black-star.ru/ 

Дана Соколова - альтернативная рок-группа, названная по имени солистки коллектива, которая является обладательницей поистине уникального голоса и эксцентричного стиля. Дана, уроженка Риги, победительница многочисленных вокальных конкурсов, впервые появилась вместе со своей группой в клипе "Индиго" (совместной работе с артистом лейбла Скруджи), который набрал около 3 млн. просмотров на YouTube. Телеканал «Пятница» - выбрал трек Даны Соколовой «Стрела» заглавным к своему популярному реалити-шоу «Пацанки», новый сезон которого стартовал на ТВ в середине августа 2017 года.</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c636731/v636731420/331cc/5e50uWhPESU.jpg" alt="Спектакль&quot;ЗАТВОРНИК И ШЕСТИПАЛЫЙ&quot; в Одном театре"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Спектакль"ЗАТВОРНИК И ШЕСТИПАЛЫЙ" в Одном театре</div><div class="text">Сказка для взрослых по мотивам повести Виктора Пелевина.

Надежда есть всегда. Стремление вырваться за рамки обыденности может привести к результату. Главная задача нашего спектакля – открыть в себе и в зрителе пространство для воображения. 
"Если ты оказался в темноте и видишь хотя бы самый слабый луч света, ты должен идти к нему, вместо того чтобы рассуждать, имеет смысл это делать или нет. Может, это действительно не имеет смысла. Но просто сидеть в темноте не имеет смысла в любом случае". 

Награды:
Победитель смотра-конкурса актёрских и режиссёрских работ в трёх номинациях:
"За оригинальное воплощение произведения" – Алексей Мосолов;
"За лучшую мужскую роль" – Артём Акатов;
"За лучшую роль второго плана" – Иван Чиров.
Победитель XV регионального фестиваля "Кубань театральная - 2016" в номинации "Лучшая (главная) мужская роль" – Артём Акатов, Михаил Золотарёв.
__________________________________________
Действующие лица и исполнители:
Затворник — Артём Акатов
Шестипалый — Михаил Золотарёв
Ближайший к кормушке — Иван Чиров
Михаил Хмыз
Одноглазка — Татьяна Башкова
Алла Мосолова
Боги (Люди) — 
Евгений Женихов, 
Богдан Медведь
Социум — 
Михаил Хмыз
Дарья Женихова
Богдан Галась
Оксана Козловская
а также студенты факультета театрального искусства КГИК

Режиссёр — Алексей Мосолов
Хореография — танцевальная компания "Воздух"
Музыкальное оформление — Артём Маров
Художник по свету — Алексей Савинов
Визуальные эффекты — Павел Подоляк
За фортепиано — Борис Борисов
Константин Пашков
___________________________________________
Премьера состоялась 10 декабря 2014 г.
Продолжительность спектакля – 1 час 45 минут без антракта.

► Телефон кассы 8 962 87 87 887.
► Билеты онлайн – кнопка "Купить билет" на сайте odinteatr.com

Адрес театра: ул. Рашпилевская, 110, 5-й этаж. Вход с ул. Калинина (между Рашпилевской и Красной)</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T17:30:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841630/v841630355/33ffb/1ONFyuB2VQw.jpg" alt="ALL IN BLACK PARTY @Sgt.Pepper's Bar | 24.11"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ALL IN BLACK PARTY @Sgt.Pepper's Bar | 24.11</div><div class="text">Белый цвет стал трендом последних месяцев. Куда ни глянь, везде он! Мы предлагаем альтернативу! Экстравагантная вечеринка – в черном цвете! ALL IN BLACK PARTY!

Надевайте свои лучшие наряды и костюмы черного цвета и готовьтесь провести удивительный вечер. А ребята PoisonStars создадут для вас неповторимую атмосферу в стиле Black, ведь именно в этот день они празднуют свое 7-летие!

Приходите отрываться! И помните, черный цвет к лицу всем!

Начало: 24 ноября в 21:00
Вход: 200 р.
Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94) 
Тел. для справок: 8 (861) 944-13-99

#SgtPeppersBar #Allinblackparty #Poisonstars</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T18:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834204/v834204768/1e1d7/EgEt2nnuHNs.jpg" alt="24 ноября – Звери tribute @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24 ноября – Звери tribute @TheRockBar</div><div class="text"> 24 ноября – трибьют группы Звери от Группы Лиц @ The Rock Bar

❤ Просто такая сильная любовь, ты еще не знаешь....А мы докладываем: 24 ноября в The Rock Bar все яркие ностальгические порывы детства вернутся с любимыми песнями Ромы Зверя! Больше 2 часов хитов группы Звери сыграют для вас Кавер-ансамбль "Группа Лиц"! Не пропустите шанс вернуться в начало нулевых вместе!!! 

The Rock Bar на Горького, 104 // пятница, 22-30 // вход 300₽</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T19:30:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639818/v639818674/6d5e4/uFi4N5u4C8g.jpg" alt="25/11 СУ-27/ V.G.N.K."></div><div class="description"><div class="name">25/11 СУ-27/ V.G.N.K.</div><div class="text">Самый мощный движняк этой осени
Начало BPM батла в 15.00
Участники:
TOCHIII      https://vk.com/id306398736
ГРЕШНИК https://vk.com/svjat2000
MELO        https://vk.com/idaun666
BUTTERFLY https://vk.com/id453704212
GLCKBY6  https://vk.com/night_evil_knock
DaviDaav  https://vk.com/davagets
Начало тусы в 17.00
Весь вечер с вами будут:
DJ KNYAZZ
https://vk.com/dj_knyazz
DMC ANTONY DEE
https://vk.com/tonny_dee
MC BULKA
https://vk.com/mcbulka
Сергей Косминов
https://vk.com/sergokosm</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T12:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">улица Ставропольская, 206</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836738/v836738163/52b1a/3hsyfNYD7PE.jpg" alt="LOUNA | 25 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">LOUNA | 25 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">Дата: 25 ноября 
18:00 - Открытие дверей 
19:00 - концерт 
Место проведения: ARENA HALL, ул.Вишняковой 1/10
_______________________________________________
КУПИТЬ БИЛЕТ: 23bileta.ru/events/concerts/louna/

ПРЕЗЕНТАЦИЯ НОВОГО АЛЬБОМА! 

Louna — российская рок-группа с женским вокалом. Некоторые журналисты называют группу «сайд-проектом» участников российской рок-группы «Tracktor Bowling», хотя сами музыканты в своих интервью опровергают этот, ошибочный по их мнению, эпитет, настаивая на том, что Louna — «это самостоятельная группа». Название образовано от творческого псевдонима вокалистки .</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Вишняковой 1/10, Arena Hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841626/v841626813/221b6/i55psTfIfnM.jpg" alt="Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы | 10 лет (Краснодар)"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы | 10 лет (Краснодар)</div><div class="text">Взвейтесь кострами, синие ночи! Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы едут покорять Юг! 
25 ноября мы впервые сыграем в Краснодаре в рамках нашего межпланетного турне в честь нашего 10-летия. Придите и узрите: танцы с енотами, поездки на космических индрикотериях, соляной бунт, революционный лосось! Будут хиты, будут редкости, будут красоты. 

Билеты: 300 р. - с репостом этого сообщения, 400 р. - в день концерта на входе. 
25 ноября, 19:00, клуб Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94).</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Чапаева ул., д. 94, Sgt.Pepper's bar</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Они совпадают так как у вас flex-direction: row, а вам нужен column

Comment: @DaemonHK что значит "для сайтов"? CSS используют для чего то другого?

Comment: @ИльяБизунов мой негативный коммент удалили, я потерял нить обсуждения)) Вообще я хотел сказать, что так верстка не оформляется, куча текста в одном контейнере, полагаясь только на переносы строк, брррр

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать `flex-direction: column;`. Но что бы это корректно работало высоту контейнера необходимо будет расчитать на javascript.

```css
.events {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 7500px;      /* необходимо расчитать */
}
.events .event {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="events"><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837436/v837436261/5dac8/g54e07y7Hzc.jpg" alt="ПАША ТЕХНИК | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ПАША ТЕХНИК | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ</div><div class="text">Два Кремля Промо представляет :

Паша Техник — в Краснодаре!
Не пропустите концерт основателя и вдохновителя эпатажной андерграунд группировки Kunteynir.
Творчество Паши Техника это настоящий андерграунд. Всем известный по выступлению на Versus Battle. Тексты наполнены неоднозначным смыслом и жизненными историями. Ребята едут в тур с поддержкой нового альбома, клипа и совершенно новым ШОУ, а так же вспомнить старые добрые треки группы KUNTEYNIR

============================
18 ноября 
Клуб : СУ-27 
Адрес: ул. Ставропольская,208
Вход с 19.00
Начало в 20.00</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул. Ставропольская,208, СУ-27</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837726/v837726550/566e3/mWWg0e-U7BY.jpg" alt="ATL | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ @ ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ATL | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ @ ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">ATL возвращается в Краснодар уже этой осенью, 18 НОЯБРЯ , ARENA HALL в рамках тура "HOLY RAVE" с новой,большой концертной программой. 

Презентация альбома "ЛИМБ" , который вызвал шквал положительных  эмоций и хороших отзывов,а также Сергей исполнит все Хиты с предыдущих альбомов и микстэйпов !
---------------------------------------------
STANDART-1000Р
FUN ZONE-1500P
-
VIP-2000P
SUPER VIP-5000P

-Купить билеты можно:

 Бургерная "Краснодарский Парень" 
Адрес: 
Ул. Северная,358
(между Красной и Красноармейской, по стороне ТЦ Галерея, в пяти минутах от ТЦ).

Часы работы:
Вс-пт 12:00-23:00 
Сб 12:00-00:00

"KEDS SHOP"
Адрес: 
Ул.Красная,176 
ТК "ЦЕНТР ГОРОДА"

Часы работы:
С 10:00-21:00
Без перерыва и выходных

 "HYPESTORE"
Адрес:
Ул.Уральская,79/1
ТРК "СБС Мегамолл"
2 этаж ( возле магазина H&amp;M )

Часы работы:
С 10:00-22:00
Без перерыва и выходных

Кофейня "TREND COFFEE SHOP"
-Адрес: 
ТЦ ОЗ молл (ул. Крылатая 2) 
Вход со стороны "Спортмастера" 

Часы работы: 10:00-22:00
Без выходных

»»КУПИТЬ БИЛЕТЫ:

-ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ БИЛЕТЫ:

• http://acidhouze.ru/

• https://krasnodar.qtickets.events/834-atl

-БИЛЕТЫ на KASSIR:

•Купить: https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/arena-hall/atl_2017-1…

•Точки продаж: https://m.vk.com/topic-151519769_36069656

-БИЛЕТЫ на 23БИЛЕТА:

•Купить: http://23bileta.ru/events/concerts/atl_krd/

•Точки продаж: https://m.vk.com/topic-151519769_36069664</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">вишняковой 1\10, arena hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841035/v841035052/24751/JQTBqPp-YT8.jpg" alt="ИЗМОРОЗЬ | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ИЗМОРОЗЬ | КРАСНОДАР | 18 НОЯБРЯ</div><div class="text">ИЗМОРОЗЬ - самая скандальная группа российской металл-сцены. Люди в чёрном запрещают их концерты на крупных площадках столицы, а лейблы готовы воевать друг с другом за издание их альбомов! 
Фанаты группы начинают устраивать слэм уже в очередях за билетами, пытаясь попасть на их концерты, но они выступают всего несколько раз в год….. 
Тексты группе своей дрожащей старческой рукой выводит загадочная Проскофья Матвеевна, от чего все «тру» металлисты либо погружаются в адовое веселье, либо сжигают диски на костре святой инквизиции. 
Песни посвящены викингам, а также различным геройским героям-воинам, нашим славянским божествам и легендам, которые частенько упоминаются в текстах. 
Здесь нет сложных ходов и гитарных запилов, зато есть запоминающиеся мелодии, броская лирика, разнообразные вокальные ходы, угар и веселье! 
Смешайте фолк, паган, блэк, добавьте юмора и приправьте всё это солью, перцем и пивом! И вы получите то, с чего никогда не замёрзнете – ИЗМОРОЗЬ. 
 
Только 18 ноября в The Rock Bar есть уникальная возможность увидеть и услышать их в «живую»! 

БИЛЕТЫ: 
В предпродаже: первые 30 билетов по 400 р. (только в The Rock Bar ,ул. Горького, 104), 
Остальные и на сайте 500р. по ссылке - https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/rock-bar/izmoroz_2017-11-18_1800

На входе 700р.</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836738/v836738163/52748/4zcKWejkmi0.jpg" alt="ATL | 18 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ATL | 18 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">Дата: 18 ноября
18:00 - Открытие дверей 
19:00 - концерт 
Место проведения: ARENA HALL, ул.Вишняковой 1/10
______________________________________
Купить Билеты: 23bileta.ru/events/concerts/atl_krd/?sphrase_id=6476

Сергей Круппов, он же ATL — талантливый исполнитель из города Новочебоксарск, представитель Белой Чувашии, разрывающий любые клубы, своими уникальными, в некотором смысле, по энергетике выступлениями.
На данный момент ATL имеет на своём счету уже 11 сольных релизов, регулярные концерты, выступление на баттле «Versus», где он одержал победу над Энди Картрайтом, а самое главное — свой уникальный стиль, наработанный годами и делающий Сергея одним из ведущих исполнителей в выбранном им творческом направлении.</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Вишняковой 1/10, Arena Hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837720/v837720877/2fe8b/Y0JhD9itJhI.jpg" alt="ДИСКОТЕКА 80-х и 90-х | КРАСНОДАР 18 ноября 2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ДИСКОТЕКА 80-х и 90-х | КРАСНОДАР 18 ноября 2017</div><div class="text">Легендарная и зажигательная Дискотека 80-х и 90-х в Краснодаре.
Будет проходить 18 ноября на сцене Баскет Холл. 
Юрий Шатунов;
Тото Кутуньо;
Валерия;
Томас Андерс;
Игорь Николаев;
Сабрина;
Оттаван;
Алексей Глызин и др.
Купить билеты в кассе или на сайте онлайн:
bil24.ru
biletovpachka.ru
Обратите внимание, что билеты предлагаются с местами или на танцпол.
Приглашаем!
Это будет незабываемый Дискач!!!</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">пригородная, 24, Баскет Холл</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c638627/v638627544/45715/pXHdO4d-ZnI.jpg" alt="ЙОРШ ||► Краснодар, 18.11.2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ЙОРШ ||► Краснодар, 18.11.2017</div><div class="text">Обжигающим светом во тьму осенней серости ворвётся музыка сильных! 
Грядущий тур группа Йорш обещает сделать особенно жарким и запоминающимся. 

Музыканты собственным примером покажут, как одна маленькая свеча может разогнать кромешную темноту и пугающий мрак. Программа #сквозьтьму станет откровенным ответом на вопросы, которые не каждый решается задать даже самому себе. 

В рамках осеннего тура Йорш разожжет огонь настоящего рока не только на площадках нашей страны, но и вырвется за ее пределы!</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T17:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841033/v841033214/396f2/5JFzxmOXt_g.jpg" alt="Легенды Русского Панка @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Легенды Русского Панка @TheRockBar</div><div class="text"> Хей, хей хей!!!! Отличная новость для любителей русского панк рока!!! 
 
 Группа РазДва, хорошо известная всем по музыкально-театральным отрывам в стиле «короля и Шута», подготовила огненную подборку отечественных хитов самого протестного стиля музыки!!! 

Панк шлягеры таких групп как: Бригадный подряд, Наив, Тараканы, Сектор Газа, Гроб, Fpg, Ляпис Трубецкой, ну и конечно же любимые Киш!!! Так же вас будут ожидать разнообразные сюрпризы, атмосфера легкого безобразия и баловства!!! 

Причесывай свой седой гребень и гоу к нам!!!! 

 #TheRockBar / 18 ноября / в 23-00 / 300₽</div><div class="date">2017-11-18T20:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c840236/v840236029/30f7d/3vY5xjHJaOw.jpg" alt="LOBODA | 20 НОЯБРЯ | КРАСНОДАР | ДС ОЛИМП"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">LOBODA | 20 НОЯБРЯ | КРАСНОДАР | ДС ОЛИМП</div><div class="text">Разыгрываем два билета на концерт LOBODA 
Будет 1 победитель!!!  (2 билета в руки) 
Условия ниже: 
1. Быть участником нашей встречи 
LOBODA  
 
2. Сделать #РЕПОСТ данной записи 18.11.2017 в 22:00 
с помощью рандомного сервиса мы выберем победителя. 
 
Билеты можно приобрести 
Онлайн : https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/ds-olimp/loboda_2017-11-20_1900 
Телефон : 8(861)203-47-87</div><div class="date">2017-11-20T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c840232/v840232133/454a4/qtoUFJJxs5A.jpg" alt="ТЕМПЕРА-ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR 23.11.17"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ТЕМПЕРА-ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR 23.11.17</div><div class="text">Выставка Краснодарских художников, разнообразных стилей и направлений в стенах SGT. PEPPER'S BAR в рамках литературно-поэтического клуба "ПОЭТИКА". 
Мир красок, глубина цвета и неисчерпаемое звучание изобразительного искусства.</div><div class="date">2017-11-23T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул.Чапаева 94, Sgt. Pepper's Bar</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841026/v841026100/36337/vufWFflwHfQ.jpg" alt="ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR | 23.11.2017"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ПОЭТИКА @SGT. PEPPER'S BAR | 23.11.2017</div><div class="text">Литературно-поэтический клуб г. Краснодара "ПОЭТИКА".
Русское слово, всегда было самой сутью нашей культуры, русская словесность поэзия, проза, и литература всемирно признанный знак качества. 

В лучшем месте г. Краснодара, в атмосфере уюта, Вы можете послушать поэтов, писателей и литераторов, тех кто через слово доносит свои идеи и открыто смотрит на мир.

Список авторов что будут жечь глаголом и звучанием сердца 23.11.2017
https://vk.com/yarmadov Арсений Ярмадов
https://vk.com/mousereepicheep Артем Козин
https://vk.com/mirror_poison Мирро Пуазон
https://vk.com/bes.dobra Артем и Коста Франич
https://vk.com/kosolapova95 Анастасия Косолапова
https://vk.com/id26336024 Лина Сальникова
https://vk.com/projectaz Школа кино "Артанде"
https://vk.com/domvlatov Андрей Домлатов
https://vk.com/id27085992 Арсен Брусенский
https://vk.com/vezdelesa Юля Постыка
https://vk.com/olejagger Олег Савранский
https://vk.com/grumpyoldman Евгений Полуянцев
https://vk.com/kain_vega Kain Vega
https://vk.com/janepaladi Евгения Баксараева</div><div class="date">2017-11-23T17:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">ул. Чапаева, 94, Sgt. Pepper's Bar</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841537/v841537136/2be74/k9jZCTJCzqU.jpg" alt="АНТОХА МС - Краснодар @Sgt.Pepper's Bar 24.11"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">АНТОХА МС - Краснодар @Sgt.Pepper's Bar 24.11</div><div class="text">Антоха МС - самое заметное и оригинальное явление на отечественной сцене за последнее время. Артист, которого нужно слушать живьем, всю музыку и тексты пишет сам, подыгрывает себе же на трубе.
Лирика, пропитанная романтикой двора, черный грув, искренность и самобытность - всё это есть в его песнях. «Нести добро» — один из его творческих принципов. На своих концертах Антоха МС делает так, что зрительный зал становится с ним единым целом.
Вот что говорит об новом альбоме сам артист:
"Данной работой мы желаем поддержать тех кто движется по самостоятельному пути, ищет опоры движения по жизни. Названием альбома - «Советы для молодожёнов» - мы желали отобразить одну из самых важных на наш взгляд тем социума - «Семья», содержимым альбома порадовать слушателей хорошим тоном, точным ритмом, родным, знакомым и новым ответом и вопросом - «Что к чему».  Приятного прослушивания."
Антоха МС - Антон Кузнецов.

Начало: 24 ноября в 19:00 
Билеты можно купить на баре в Sgt. Pepper's Bar по 800 р.
Билет на двоих: 1400 р.
Билет на троих: 2000 р. 
Электронные билеты: https://vk.cc/7g4Hch
Возрастное ограничение: 16+
Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94) 
Тел. для справок: 8 (861) 944-13-99 

#SgtPeppersBar #АнтохаМС</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837223/v837223500/575d3/3BALaOHaD7Q.jpg" alt="24 ноября - СЭТ @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24 ноября - СЭТ @TheRockBar</div><div class="text">Один из главных краснодарских артистов объявил о перезапуске своей карьеры. 
 
24 ноября в The Rock Bar - эксклюзивно, до выхода нового релиза - СЭТ презентует абсолютно новые треки и исполнит свое лучшее из 5-ти изданных альбомов, в том числе хиты, записанные с Кастой, Krec, Триадой, L'One и др. 
 
Концерт пройдет при участии живого бэнда. Специальные гости: Лейла и PLC.
 
Билеты: 
Билеты в предпродаже по 500р в The Rock Bar на Горького, 104 или по ссылке - https://krd.kassir.ru/koncert/rock-bar/set_2017-11-24_1900
В день концерта 700р</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639918/v639918568/620db/BuhJ1OhDShU.jpg" alt="24.11 - Дана Соколова @ Краснодар"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24.11 - Дана Соколова @ Краснодар</div><div class="text">24 ноября в краснодарском клубе Arena Hall состоится большой сольный концерт Даны Соколовой ! 

Подробности: https://vk.com/danakrasnodar 

Подробная информация о билетах доступна по ссылке: https://dana.black-star.ru/ 

Дана Соколова - альтернативная рок-группа, названная по имени солистки коллектива, которая является обладательницей поистине уникального голоса и эксцентричного стиля. Дана, уроженка Риги, победительница многочисленных вокальных конкурсов, впервые появилась вместе со своей группой в клипе "Индиго" (совместной работе с артистом лейбла Скруджи), который набрал около 3 млн. просмотров на YouTube. Телеканал «Пятница» - выбрал трек Даны Соколовой «Стрела» заглавным к своему популярному реалити-шоу «Пацанки», новый сезон которого стартовал на ТВ в середине августа 2017 года.</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c636731/v636731420/331cc/5e50uWhPESU.jpg" alt="Спектакль&quot;ЗАТВОРНИК И ШЕСТИПАЛЫЙ&quot; в Одном театре"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Спектакль"ЗАТВОРНИК И ШЕСТИПАЛЫЙ" в Одном театре</div><div class="text">Сказка для взрослых по мотивам повести Виктора Пелевина.

Надежда есть всегда. Стремление вырваться за рамки обыденности может привести к результату. Главная задача нашего спектакля – открыть в себе и в зрителе пространство для воображения. 
"Если ты оказался в темноте и видишь хотя бы самый слабый луч света, ты должен идти к нему, вместо того чтобы рассуждать, имеет смысл это делать или нет. Может, это действительно не имеет смысла. Но просто сидеть в темноте не имеет смысла в любом случае". 

Награды:
Победитель смотра-конкурса актёрских и режиссёрских работ в трёх номинациях:
"За оригинальное воплощение произведения" – Алексей Мосолов;
"За лучшую мужскую роль" – Артём Акатов;
"За лучшую роль второго плана" – Иван Чиров.
Победитель XV регионального фестиваля "Кубань театральная - 2016" в номинации "Лучшая (главная) мужская роль" – Артём Акатов, Михаил Золотарёв.
__________________________________________
Действующие лица и исполнители:
Затворник — Артём Акатов
Шестипалый — Михаил Золотарёв
Ближайший к кормушке — Иван Чиров
Михаил Хмыз
Одноглазка — Татьяна Башкова
Алла Мосолова
Боги (Люди) — 
Евгений Женихов, 
Богдан Медведь
Социум — 
Михаил Хмыз
Дарья Женихова
Богдан Галась
Оксана Козловская
а также студенты факультета театрального искусства КГИК

Режиссёр — Алексей Мосолов
Хореография — танцевальная компания "Воздух"
Музыкальное оформление — Артём Маров
Художник по свету — Алексей Савинов
Визуальные эффекты — Павел Подоляк
За фортепиано — Борис Борисов
Константин Пашков
___________________________________________
Премьера состоялась 10 декабря 2014 г.
Продолжительность спектакля – 1 час 45 минут без антракта.

► Телефон кассы 8 962 87 87 887.
► Билеты онлайн – кнопка "Купить билет" на сайте odinteatr.com

Адрес театра: ул. Рашпилевская, 110, 5-й этаж. Вход с ул. Калинина (между Рашпилевской и Красной)</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T17:30:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841630/v841630355/33ffb/1ONFyuB2VQw.jpg" alt="ALL IN BLACK PARTY @Sgt.Pepper's Bar | 24.11"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">ALL IN BLACK PARTY @Sgt.Pepper's Bar | 24.11</div><div class="text">Белый цвет стал трендом последних месяцев. Куда ни глянь, везде он! Мы предлагаем альтернативу! Экстравагантная вечеринка – в черном цвете! ALL IN BLACK PARTY!

Надевайте свои лучшие наряды и костюмы черного цвета и готовьтесь провести удивительный вечер. А ребята PoisonStars создадут для вас неповторимую атмосферу в стиле Black, ведь именно в этот день они празднуют свое 7-летие!

Приходите отрываться! И помните, черный цвет к лицу всем!

Начало: 24 ноября в 21:00
Вход: 200 р.
Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94) 
Тел. для справок: 8 (861) 944-13-99

#SgtPeppersBar #Allinblackparty #Poisonstars</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T18:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834204/v834204768/1e1d7/EgEt2nnuHNs.jpg" alt="24 ноября – Звери tribute @TheRockBar"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">24 ноября – Звери tribute @TheRockBar</div><div class="text"> 24 ноября – трибьют группы Звери от Группы Лиц @ The Rock Bar

 Просто такая сильная любовь, ты еще не знаешь....А мы докладываем: 24 ноября в The Rock Bar все яркие ностальгические порывы детства вернутся с любимыми песнями Ромы Зверя! Больше 2 часов хитов группы Звери сыграют для вас Кавер-ансамбль "Группа Лиц"! Не пропустите шанс вернуться в начало нулевых вместе!!! 

The Rock Bar на Горького, 104 // пятница, 22-30 // вход 300₽</div><div class="date">2017-11-24T19:30:00.000Z</div><div class="address"></div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639818/v639818674/6d5e4/uFi4N5u4C8g.jpg" alt="25/11 СУ-27/ V.G.N.K."></div><div class="description"><div class="name">25/11 СУ-27/ V.G.N.K.</div><div class="text">Самый мощный движняк этой осени
Начало BPM батла в 15.00
Участники:
TOCHIII      https://vk.com/id306398736
ГРЕШНИК https://vk.com/svjat2000
MELO        https://vk.com/idaun666
BUTTERFLY https://vk.com/id453704212
GLCKBY6  https://vk.com/night_evil_knock
DaviDaav  https://vk.com/davagets
Начало тусы в 17.00
Весь вечер с вами будут:
DJ KNYAZZ
https://vk.com/dj_knyazz
DMC ANTONY DEE
https://vk.com/tonny_dee
MC BULKA
https://vk.com/mcbulka
Сергей Косминов
https://vk.com/sergokosm</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T12:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">улица Ставропольская, 206</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836738/v836738163/52b1a/3hsyfNYD7PE.jpg" alt="LOUNA | 25 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">LOUNA | 25 ноября | Краснодар | ARENA HALL</div><div class="text">Дата: 25 ноября 
18:00 - Открытие дверей 
19:00 - концерт 
Место проведения: ARENA HALL, ул.Вишняковой 1/10
_______________________________________________
КУПИТЬ БИЛЕТ: 23bileta.ru/events/concerts/louna/

ПРЕЗЕНТАЦИЯ НОВОГО АЛЬБОМА! 

Louna — российская рок-группа с женским вокалом. Некоторые журналисты называют группу «сайд-проектом» участников российской рок-группы «Tracktor Bowling», хотя сами музыканты в своих интервью опровергают этот, ошибочный по их мнению, эпитет, настаивая на том, что Louna — «это самостоятельная группа». Название образовано от творческого псевдонима вокалистки .</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T15:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Вишняковой 1/10, Arena Hall</div></div></div><div class="event"><div class="image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841626/v841626813/221b6/i55psTfIfnM.jpg" alt="Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы | 10 лет (Краснодар)"></div><div class="description"><div class="name">Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы | 10 лет (Краснодар)</div><div class="text">Взвейтесь кострами, синие ночи! Кобыла и Трупоглазые Жабы едут покорять Юг! 
25 ноября мы впервые сыграем в Краснодаре в рамках нашего межпланетного турне в честь нашего 10-летия. Придите и узрите: танцы с енотами, поездки на космических индрикотериях, соляной бунт, революционный лосось! Будут хиты, будут редкости, будут красоты. 

Билеты: 300 р. - с репостом этого сообщения, 400 р. - в день концерта на входе. 
25 ноября, 19:00, клуб Sgt. Pepper's Bar (ул. Чапаева, 94).</div><div class="date">2017-11-25T16:00:00.000Z</div><div class="address">Чапаева ул., д. 94, Sgt.Pepper's bar</div></div></div></div>
```