# Вертикальное выравнивание списков в колонках (с использованием flexbox)

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Добрый день, коллеги!
Возможно решение простое, но пока в голову оно не приходит.

Есть список, который может быть в две, три или четыре колонки, реализован с помощью флексбокс модели.

Допустим список в три колонки, берем первый ряд по горизонтали, в первом и последнем элементе контента на одну строку, а в среднем например на три, соответственно второй ряд по горизонтали будет отталкиваться от самого высокого элемента.

Но нужно чтоб нижний отступ у невысоких элементов не зависел от высоты соседа и элементы шли друг за другом.

```css
ul.grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\25CF";
  margin: 0.1rem 10px 0 20px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
ul.grid li {
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
}
ul.grid.three-columns li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 33.3%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.3%;
  flex: 0 0 33.3%;
}
ul.grid.three-columns li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul.grid.three-columns li:nth-child(3n) {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid three-columns">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amerem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```

[Пример списка](https://jsfiddle.net/904p30wz/2/)

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758412/Вывод-в-две-колонки-flexbox/758416

Comment: используйте columns

Comment: В этом случае нужна фиксированная высота, чтоб элементы упирались и переносились, а предполагается, что контент будет добавляться либо удаляться